# Create set of data frames using sample from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sample

The following reproducible example will give me a mtcars dataset but where the values of the variable mpg is randomly shuffled within each cylinder group, using the `sample()` function from dplyr.

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
          mutate(mpg = mpg[sample(row_number())]) %>%
          as.data.frame()
```

My problem is fairly simple. I want to create a list with n amount of these shuffled data frames. This is, of cource, easily done with a loop but I suppose it is simple to do it without a loop as well. How can this be done?

Comment: Can you show complete or part of your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah The output would be equivalent to the result from the following code
`
my_list <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
my_list[[i]] <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
          mutate(mpg = mpg[sample(row_number())]) %>%
          as.data.frame()}
`

Comment: You can just do `purrr::map(1:n, ~ mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% 
      mutate(mpg = mpg[sample(row_number())]) %>%
      as.data.frame() )`  where `n` is however many you want to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function to shuffle the data

```
library(dplyr)

shuffle_data <- function(data) {
   data %>% group_by(cyl) %>%  mutate(mpg = mpg[sample(row_number())])
}
```

and use `replicate` to create a list of length `n`.

```
n <- 10
my_list <- replicate(n, shuffle_data(mtcars), simplify = FALSE)
```